# How to diagnose performance issues on my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, raspberry-pi

I've made a website that displays certain posts from Instagram, Facebook and Twitter. The website shows these posts in card form with certain animations and transitions. It works fine on the desktop but the goal is to run it on raspberry PIs and, when run from one of those, the animations and videos stutter. I want to reduce or eliminate the stutter and I'm considering several approaches:

- web workers to offload some of the animation calculations to a separate CPU core
- dynamic video compression on the server depending on what device will be playing the video
- different animation methods

To figure out if any of these would help I'd want to first figure out what is actually causing the stutter but I don't know how to do this. I need a way to figure out what portion of the slowdown is due to what issue. Like, what's the impact of loading the images/videos, the impact of playing the video, of animating the elements etc. What is the best way of doing this?

[Here](https://socialfeed.test.dbtouch.com/FeedDisplay/--PRIVATE--JJMtCako1DPqIqRe) is the working version of the site if that will help with the suggestions. Note that I'm not highly experienced with JS or programing in general and I was just starting out when I created this so it's far from optimal but now I need to figure out the best way to improve it.

Comment: Use for example Chrome devTools. In "Performance" tab you will see everything that you will need from script evaluation time to animation fps. You can also use "Lighthouse" extension to find performance issues but it is not as specific as "performance" tab. In conclusion Performance tab will provide you with data but will not tell you what has to be improved. Lighthouse will provide you with list of issues to fix but it doesn't takes everything into account.

Comment: This question is far too broad. It is expected that you do some research on your own and narrow your question down. Stack Overflow is not a site where you can just link to a website and ask volunteers to diagnose your performance problems; many of us do that professionally. See [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552). Also, asking for the "best way" is going to lead to spam and, well, referrals to people's professional services. Something Stack Overflow does not want.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a solution, simply a starting point, I did a deep dive into chrome dev tools and figured out the issue and started another question with more specifics (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643608/can-i-optimize-an-animation-thats-slowed-down-by-the-raserize-paint-process-as). The link isn't there so someone can diagnose the site for me, only to help pick the best tool to analyze it, as I wasn't sure if there was a bunch of choices and if they were dependent on what you were using them with. I'd accept the chrome devtools answer if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a performance issue, but it could be something else. If you're using VNC Viewer or some other form of remote desktop, it could be because of that. If it's just wired to a monitor, though, it's most likely the fact that the CPU can't handle it. You could try to install a more lightweight browser, because Chromium can really take a toll on the CPU. Go to Chrome DevTools, and go to the performance tab. This should show you basically everything you need to know. I'm not sure if you're using CSS transitions or something else, so I can't really help you there. You could try NetSurf or Dillo as more lightweight browsers, though.